# Smooth image movement based on time interval?

Tags: javascript, html, animation

The code below should shift the image "avaOne" either left or right based upon a user input. THis works, but the movement is "choppy". I tried to set the image shift value to only one pixel (if the user presses "left" the image will go left by one pixel at a time), then repeat this one pixel movement a certain amount of times per second to get a smoother image shift. This does not seem to work properly. If anyone knows how to achieve this smooth image shift effect based upon user input, it would be greatly appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            #avaOne {position: absolute; left: 0px; width: 50px;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img id="avaOne" src="avaOne.png"/>
    </body>
    <script>
        var xPos = 300;
        var tick = 100;
        //avaOne speed is equal to 1000/tick in px per second. (A tick value of 100 would mean that avaOne would have a speed of 10px/second.)
        
        //LEFT  - 37
        //RIGHT - 39
        var i = setInterval(window.addEventListener("keydown", function shift(event) {
            if (event.keyCode == 37) {
                xPos--;
            } else if (event.keyCode == 39) {
                xPos++;
            }
            document.getElementById("avaOne").style.left = xPos.toString() + "px";
        }), tick);
    </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make it smoother updating the value of xPos to a bigger difference in between events and then adding transition property to the style.

Play with this values depending on what effect you are looking for.

Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            #avaOne {position: absolute; left: 300px; width: 50px; 
                     transition:linear .15s;} <!-- Change here -->
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img id="avaOne" src="avaOne.png"/>
    </body>
    <script>
        var xPos = 300;
        //LEFT  - 37
        //RIGHT - 39
        window.addEventListener("keydown", function shift(event) {
            if (event.keyCode == 37) {
                xPos -= 5; // Change here
            } else if (event.keyCode == 39) {
                xPos += 5; // Change here
            }
            document.getElementById("avaOne").style.left = xPos.toString() + "px";
        }) 
    </script>
</html>
```